# How to open a code:blocks c++ project in netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, codeblocks

I have a project which works perfectly in code:blocks with the MinGW compiler.

I go to open the project in netbeans and only the "***bin***" and "***obj***" directories are showing.

Is there  a proper way to open code:block projects in netbeans?

Comment: Well, Code::Blocks can import a bunch of different formats, but won't export its projects, only saving them in it's own format. If there's not an import option in Netbeans, you'll have to create a project and then add your existing code/header files to it.

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing :( @enhzflep

Comment: I've done it but now all my includes are errors @enhzflep

Comment: You'll probably find that the two different IDEs setup their own environment variables which dictate the locations of various files amongst other stuff. If you've included  bunch of stuff `<likeThis>` instead of `"likeThis"`, then you're relying upon the paths, which will be different for the 2 IDEs. It's more or less a matter of solving them 1 by one.

Comment: I thought anything included `"likeThis"` was a user included filed, where `<likeThis>` is a built in library @enhzflep

Comment: That's the way that they're generally used, but whenever I get sqlite stuff for instance, I chuck the .a file in the default library folder and the .h file in the default include folder. You can also modify the list of default folders so that they point to your own projects.. Do understand, there's little chance for anything more than conjecture when there's (a) no error messages and codes in your question and (b) none of the source-code that causes the offending msgs. You could always edit your question and add some (a) and (b) for a higher chance of a useful response. :)

Answer (score 0):

At first step You can use [cdb2make](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/topic,13675.0.html) to generate Makefile's,
and in Netbeans IDE create the new project this existing sources... :)